# Не вызывается функция по onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой JS код:

```
$(function() {
   //тут отправляем пробегаем по массиву и выводим каждый элемент {
     $("#block").append("<a href='javascript:;' onclick='my_func(1, 10)'>Link</a>");
   //}

   function new_func(....) {
       .....
   }
});

function my_func(id, amt) {
   ....
   new_func();
}
```

После клика на добавленную ссылку должна вызваться функция **my_func** , там выполняется код, и после должна вызваться функция **new_func** , но вызова не происходит, получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: new_func is not defined
>
> at my_func
>
> at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Пробовал поместить **my_func** под *$(function() {* но тогда получаю такую ошибку:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: my_func is not defined
>
> at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Что я делаю не так?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#block").append("<a href='javascript:;' onclick='my_func(1, 10);'>Link</a>");

  function new_func() {
    console.log('new_func');
  }
});

function my_func(id, amt) {
  console.log(amt);
  new_func();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="block"></div>
```

Comment: `onclick` здесь совершенно не при чем, вы из глобальной области видимости хотите увидеть функцию внутри изолированной области видимости `($(function() {});` так не получится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предложу дом елементы создавать не как строку а как дом елементы :

```js
(function() {

  let a = document.createElement('a')
  a.textContent = '123'
  a.href = 'javascript:;'
  a.onclick = () => myFunc(1, 2)

  document.getElementById('block').appendChild(a)

  function myFunc(id, amt) {
    console.log(amt)
    newFunc()
  }

  function newFunc() {
    console.log('newFunc')
  }
})();
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

тут правда без `JQuery`

Comment: не совсем понял в чем тут суть(я не очень в javascript)

Comment: суть в обастях видимости, если не очень в js, то советую ченить почитать про него )

Comment: @iKey совсем на пальцах - в вашем коде myfunc используется jquery, когда прописывается обработчик. и он его не видит. А в предложенном варианте обработчик назначается в той же области видимости, что и объявление функции